# Methods to convert mathematical formulas into code in Matlab, C++, etc?

Tags: c++, math, matlab, wolfram-mathematica

I have a basic question for all of the math experts out there.

"If I have an academic paper, whats the easiest way to convert a simple mathematical equation into working Matlab (or C++) code?"

Ideally, there would be a Latex >> Matlab (or C++) conversion tool.

However, failing this, is there a "cheat sheet" which contains all of the common mathematical symbols, and their equivalent implementation keywords in Matlab (or R, or C++)?

Comment: This is probably not the answer you are looking for: go to a unversity, take at least one or two semesters mathematics, unless you can read and understand those academic papers, and also learn Matlab/and or C++. Then - perhaps - you will be able to convert a paper into code. IMHO there no short-cut to this.

Comment: The whole point of programming is to translate things which people can read and understand into things which machines can run.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use [Mathematica Symbolic Computation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/SymbolicComputation.html).

You can enter mathematical equations straight into Mathematica, then export the result as C code.

Keep tweaking the equation until the rendering looks identical to the original equation in the academic paper. You can then plug your own parameters in, and Mathematica will calculate the result for you.

You can even do cool things such as ask it to differentiate the equation - and it will produce the differential, and printout the resulting equation.

You can call Mathematica from any language, including .NET, Q, Python, Java, etc.

You could even compile the Mathematica program into a .NET assembly and embed it into your app.

Mathematica will also emit Java or C code that matches the mathematical formula you have just entered.

Comment: Just as in the case with any other programming language, you need to conform to strict rules when entering expressions into Mathematica (despite these expressions being designed to look similar to mathematical notation for readability).  I am not aware of Mathematica being able to produce either Java or .NET compatible code.

Comment: Yes, Mathematica has features for importing a subset of LaTeX formulae, it even has a feature for trying to guess what they mean.  But you need to understand the meaning of the formulae and correct them yourself.  Take e.g. `ToExpression["$J_3(x)$", TeXForm]`.  It gives you a Bessel function.  There's no guarantee that the author of the original paper actually meant a Bessel function by `J`.  As many others have pointed out, there are many tools that assist with conversion of a formula between different representations, but ultimately it's up to you to understand them and make the prog work.

Answer (score 9):

I've never seen such a thing. Most mathematical notation is written to be understood by a person of (at least) reasonable intelligence, so it frequently omits all sorts of details that would be necessary to produce working code. If you had such a tool, I doubt it would produce usable results more than (maybe) 10% of the time.

The reverse seems a great deal more tenable -- producing readable mathematical notation from code (especially from something like Matlab) sounds much more reasonable. It's much easier to omit information that's present than to try to synthesize information that's missing.

Comment: Quite true. But sometimes it would be very handy to create a command-line script (in some language) from an expression found in a document. However, a major problem is that most documents are in the PDF format, and so the formulas are actually nothing more than graphical objects...

Comment: But the reverse has a very similar problem - when I want to understand what some algorithm, esepecially a mathematical one does, I can dig myself through the code (a process of days or weeks) or I could ask the author for a short, human-understandable outline. I don't think the latter can be easily automated.

Comment: @Doc Brown: Don't get me wrong: I don't expect to see a tool to convert large chunks of (say) C++ to really readable descriptions any time soon. Nonetheless, I can at least *imagine* such a thing producing halfway usable results, where I find it hard to even imagine going the other direction.

Comment: if you ever find such a tool within the next 10 years or so which can produce useful results, let me know ;-)

Comment: @Doc Brown. See my latest answer.

Comment: I have this problem.. I am a person of reasonable intelligence, but when it comes to equations, my intelligence is limited. My mathematician is always trying to help me out with equasions I can implement in code, but its tough because he doesn't speak computer, and I don't speak complex math. In the end I tell him to it in Excel.. if he can get his result in Excel, I can duplicate it in code

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible. Generally, mathematical expressions in papers are made for humans to understand, as Jerry Coffin said. Because of this, there are all sorts of issues. One I think off the top of my head is optimality. (Mathematical) code for human consumption is rarely optimal, bad example is the Fibonacci sequence. Nobody would write Fibonacci code as humans understand it.

So, even if you did get the code parsed, you'll still have so much work to do it's the same as just writing it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The question is based on a core assumption - computers do everything better.  This is not the case.

Computers and specifically computational machines tend to do iterative tasks better than humans and cognitive tasks worse.  Is the maths you're trying to convert iterative or cognitive?  If its iterative then the standard procedure - for x do n times or while (criterion) do etc... would be simple to use for iterative tasks.  If you're delving into AI and machine learning there is a wealth of information out there as to how computers are supposed to do AI and do it well. I'm assuming that the questioner is asking for help from a cognitive sense and not iterative.  Hence the problem - and lack of solution.  If the task is cognitive to implement then computational machines will not help you.